# I want to save urdu scrape data into csv file but when i open the file the format of file is not readable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```py
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(record,columns['Title','Category','Headline','Summary','ImgLink','Details'])

df

df.to_csv("page1.csv",encoding='utf-8')
```

[image]

I want to store in this format

[image]

But file save in this format

Comment: The real solution is to use something less braindead than Excel to read the data.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with CSV is that it is a text file.  To show it as UTF-8, you need to do something different.  To open the csv file, don't double click on the csv file.

The following is for Excel 2007: for your version of Excel, it may be slightly different.

1. Open Excel
2. Select the **Data Menu**
3. Select the **From Text** option
4. Select the CSV file
5. Make sure the **File origin** is set to 65001: Unicode (UTF-8).  You should now see the Urdu/Arabic.
6. Set the delimiters

You should now see the file as expected.

If you wish to double click on the file, do not save it as CSV.  Save it as xlsx using either openpyxl or xlsxwriter.

Alternatively, use LibreOffice Calc as your default for opening CSV files - it goes straight into the LibreOffice Calc equivalent of **From Text**